# What's the relationship between all sets of $gHg^{-1}$ when H is non-normal

Tags: group-theory

when H is order r subgroup of G, $gHg^{-1}$ is yet anther order r subgroup of G.
suppose H is non-normal, mark all subgroups produced by H as Set: {$gHg^{(-1)}$ | for all g in G}
I tried dihedral d_4 with order 2 non-normal subgroup, there are total 4 of them,
$H_1$,$H_2$,$H_3$,$H_4$, where $H_1$={e,f}, $H_2$={e,rf}, $H_3$={e,$r^2f$} etc, where r is rotate, f is flip.

all $gHg^{-1}$ produced by(reachable by) $H_1$ is {$H_1$,$H_3$},

all $gHg^{-1}$ produced by(reachable by) $H_2$ is {$H_2$,$H_4$},

all $gHg^{-1}$ produced by(reachable by) $H_3$ is {$H_1$,$H_3$},

all $gHg^{-1}$ produced by(reachable by) $H_4$ is {$H_2$,$H_4$},

I tried d_5 with order 2 non-normal subgroup,$H_1$,$H_2$,$H_3$,$H_4$,$H_5$

all $gHg^{-1}$ produced by(reachable by) $H_1$ is {$H_1$,$H_2$,$H_3$,$H_4$,$H_5$},

I tried d_6 with order 2 non-normal subgroup,$H_1$,$H_2$,$H_3$,$H_4$,$H_5$,$H_6$

all $gHg^{-1}$ produced by(reachable by) $H_1$ is {$H_1$,$H_3$,$H_5$},

all $gHg^{-1}$ produced by(reachable by) $H_2$ is {$H_2$,$H_4$,$H_6$},

similarly, d_n when n is odd, the reachable sets is all $H_1$,$H_2$,...H_n,
d_n when n is even, it splits into {$H_1$,$H_3$,$H_5$...}, and {$H_2$,$H_4$,$H_6$...}

if you think all $gHg^{-1}$ produced by H as equivalent to H, it forms some kind of equivalent relationship,then $H_1$~$H_2$,$H_2$~$H_3$ => $H_1$~$H_3$ (it's easy to proof),

so at least from dihedral group, it seemed that all sets have same size,
so my question is:

1. would all sets S of $gHg^{-1}$ produced by H has same size? (every element in S is a subgroup produced by some $gHg^{-1}$)
2. the size of set S divides total number of non-normal order r subgroups of G?
   (if 1 holds then 2 holds, if 1 not hold 2 can still be true)

from equivalent class point of view, it seemed different sets kind of
related?in one set, $H_1$~$H_3$~$H_5$, in another set $H_2$~$H_4$~$H_6$, very similar.

Edit:
Derek Holt provides a counterexample
to both my questions is $_3×_5$
considering subgroups of order 2
. The sizes of sets 
are 3
, 5
, and 15
, with 23
such subgroups in total.

so both my first 2 questions are false.
but ponder at the example, there's still relationship
between the conjugate groups, since 3 and 5 both
divides the largest set size 15, (my thought process
is that it hints there is some symmetry hiding
between those conjugate groups sets). So my question
now becomes :

would all the set size generated by conjugate group
all divides the largest set size generated by conjugate group?
(like in the counterexample 3 and 5 both divides 15)

Comment: Your set is the orbit of $H$ under the $G$-action by conjugation on the set of all the subgroups of $G$.

Comment: Btw, capital letters and formatting are important: your post is poor under both points.

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: A counterexample to both questions is $D_3 \times D_5$ considering subgroups of order $2$. The sizes of your sets $S$ are $3$, $5$, and $15$, with $23$ such subgroups in total.

Comment: +1, though. Nice research attitude/effort.

Comment: Derek Holt's example is correct, quite fascinating you found this counterexample, but I found another relationship between those subgroups, 3+5+15 = 23 so 23 can't be divided by any of them. but 3*5=15, it appeared those conjugate subgroups still have some relationship. with 3 & 5 divides largest set size(15). Is it possible to find completely unrelated conjugate subgroups?

Comment: $S_5$ has $25$ subgroups of order $2$ with two conjugacy classes of sizes $10$ and $15$.

Comment: Though false in general, another example where 1 and 2 hold true is $S_4$ for $r=4$. This group has three conjugate copies of $C_4$ and three conjugate copies of $C_2\times C_2$.

Comment: wouldn't $C_2\times C_2$ just be order 2?